# How to boot Ubuntu as third OS and how to configure 3-OS loader?

Tags: boot

I have both Windows 7 and Windows 10 installed on my computer and I can choose which one I want to load.

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 but I don't know how to boot it. I still have the two choices between Windows 7 and 10.

I have another computer with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, and I can choose between these two operating systems while booting.

Now I guess the problem is that I have Ubuntu as my 3rd system here. How can I handle this?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? What brand/model system? Generally grub only finds one Windows install as second install of Windows overwrites first installs boot and adds second Windows entry to BCD. Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: maybe rEFInd would suit your needs if your machine uses UEFI. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your system still has FastBoot enabled. Can you enter the BIOS of your system? It is usually F2 or F12 or some other function key based on your computer make. Once in there, disable FastBoot and also you could change your boot priority so that Ubuntu is higher than Windows. If you can post screenshots (photos) of what you're seeing in BIOS, we can help you get Ubuntu to boot. Good luck!